# Create a custom html table from a multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, database

2hours i'm searching for a solution of my problem but no result found yet. I have an array ($array) that i created from my database with a foreach loop. When i use var_dump($array) i get this :

```
array(2) {
  [a1] => array(4) {
    [b1] => string(2) "32"
    [b2] => string(2) "98"
    [b3] => string(2) "45"
    [b4] => string(3) "654"
  }
  [a2] => array(3) {
    [b1] => string(3) "677"
    [b2] => string(2) "12"
    [b3] => string(3) "430"
  }
}
```

What is important here is that my array ($array) store informations which are selected from database and stored in $array like this way :

```
$array[a1][b1] = 32;
$array[a1][b2] = 98;
$array[a1][b3] = 45;
$array[a1][b4] = 654;
$array[a2][b1] = 677;
$array[a2][b2] = 12;
$array[a2][b3] = 430;
```

Now the problem that i have is how to show $array in html table like this way :

```
Html table wanted:
 _____________________
|      |  a1  |  a2  |
|______|______|______|
| b1   |  32  |  677 |
|______|______|______|
| b2   |  98  |  12  |
|______|______|______|
| b3   |  45  |  430 |
|______|______|______|
| b4   |  654 |      |
|______|______|______|
```

Also i need one more thing is that the values of table row(1,2) and col(1,2,3,4) are stored in 2 tables in database like this way :

```
tableA :
 ______________
| ID   | NAME | 
|______|______|
|  1   |  a1  | 
|______|______|
|  2   |  a2  |  
|______|______|

tableB :
 ______________
| ID   | NAME | 
|______|______|
|  1   |  b1  | 
|______|______|
|  2   |  b2  |  
|______|______|
|  3   |  b3  |
|______|______|
|  4   |  b4  |     
|______|______|
```

How can i show the array : $array into an html table like "Html table wanted" ?

A Million of Thanks for any one who can help me in this issue .

Comment: You seem to be asking two different questions here: How can I create a multidimensional array from my database, and also how can I translate that into a X-Y table in HTML. Is that correct?

Comment: No. I created the multidimensional array from the database and i put the structure of array that i have. I need only how to create the html table with that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//fetch values for a into associative array
$aValues = fetch_assoc("SELECT * tableA");

//fetch values for b into associative array
$bValues = fetch_assoc("SELECT * tableB");

$htmlTable = '<table>';

//adding header row
$htmlTable .= '<tr><td></td>';
foreach ($aValues as $aValue) {
    $htmlTable .= '<td>' . $aValue['name'] . '<td>';
}
$htmlTable .= '</tr>';

//adding other rows, this assumes your $array is already generated
foreach ($bValues as $bValue) {
    $htmlTable .= '<tr>';
    $htmlTable .= '<td>' . $bValue['name'] . '</td>';

    foreach ($aValues as $aValue) {
        if (isset($array[$aValue['name']][$bValue['name']])) {
            $cellValue = $array[$aValue['name']][$bValue['name']];
        } else {
            $cellValue = '';
        }

        $htmlTable .= '<td>' . $cellValue . '<td>';
    }

    $htmlTable .= '</tr>';
}

$htmlTable .= '</table>';
```

Comment: Thank you, that exactly what i want.